# changing swf through reverse engineering

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, reverse-engineering, ffdec

My aim is to change compiled swf flash games so they would send score to server through http. Unfortunately I only have compiled swf files. I would like to know is it even possible to make such changes with only decompilation, reverse engineering, etc. I have found a program called JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler (ffdec), but it only works with AS2. In AS3 I can see all the code but I cannot change anything bigger than constants. Do you know of any solution that would work with both AS2 and AS3 (probably not the same one)?

PS: For better or worse I am loading these swf into another one as a child, so apparently for example 'laodVariables' is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have permission from the people who made those games to modify them in this way, in that case I recommend asking them for the source code and recompiling the games with the features you want.  If you don't have permission then you shouldn't be doing this, so don't.

Comment: First of all, this is not an **answer**. And secondly, while I agree with your sentiment, game modding is usually a gray area - I've rarely heard any mod getting official recognition, let alone support from the developer. Source code is most likely out of the question - But that doesn't make this question invalid, or inherently bad. Think about it, streaming video games is, technically speaking, copyright infringement. Do you avoid watching those as well?